# Resizable table columns with bz code

Tags: javascript, html-table, resizable

I've created a resizable table columns code by following [bz's demo](http://bz.var.ru/comp/web/resizable.html)

But when I create more than 30 columns, the code does not work. The table I'm creating is pretty simple:

```
<table class="resizable" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td name="col1" align="center">Column 1</td>
            <td name="col2" align="center">Column 2</td>
            <td name="col3" align="center">Column 3</td>
            <td name="col4" align="center">Column 4</td>
            <td name="col5" align="center">Column 5</td>
            <td name="col6" align="center">Column 6</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Does anyone have any ideas which line should I change to make the code work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not doing it on your own? Make a Table resizeable is pretty simple:

First add this to your onLoad:

```
$(".gridTableSeparator").bind("mousedown", function () {
    var that = $(this).parent();
    $("body").bind("mousemove", function (event) {
        that.attr("width", event.pageX - that.offset().left);
    });
    $("body").bind("mouseup", function (event) {
       $(this).unbind("mousemove mouseup");
    });
 });
```

Your table Header should look like this:

```
<td>
    <div class="gridTableSeparator"></div>
    <div class="gridTableHeadline">Tableheadline</div>
</td>
```

And format the separator and the headline like this:

```
.gridTableSeparator 
{
  width: 3px; 
  right:-4px;
  height:40px;
  float:right;    
  position:relative;  
  cursor: e-resize;  
}
.gridTableHeadline 
{
  line-height: 40px;  
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

benefits of doing it on your own is that you have the full control and can change the look and functionality for your needs. Otherwise it would be great if you can post a fiddle, so we can see what went wrong if you add more than 30 rows.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I'm trying not to use `<div>` tag. Do you have other example I could refer to? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can use this [jQuery plugin] (http://quocity.com/colresizable/). Don't know if you want to use jQuery?

Comment: Thanks for your example. But the code still doesn't work if I create many columns.

Comment: Actually 30 isn't an exact number, but if there are many columns, the last column usually cannot be resized. Do you have any idea how do I write the code, so that there is always a space beside the last column? Thanks.

Comment: @JanHommes There is no jQuery tag in this question. Therefore, I would appreciate an answer NOT relying on jQuery.