# Horizontally Scrollable HTML table with resizing

Tags: html, scroll, html-table, resize

I have the html table like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="gridTableSeparator"></div>
                <div class="gridTableHeadline">aaa</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="gridTableSeparator"></div>
                <div class="gridTableHeadline">bbb</div>
            </td>
             <td>
                <div class="gridTableSeparator"></div>
                <div class="gridTableHeadline">ccc</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="gridTableSeparator"></div>
                <div class="gridTableHeadline">ddd</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and my Js:

```
$(".gridTableSeparator").bind("mousedown", function () {
    var that = $(this).parent();
    $("body").bind("mousemove", function (event) {
        that.attr("width", event.pageX - that.offset().left);
    });
    $("body").bind("mouseup", function (event) {
       $(this).unbind("mousemove mouseup");
    });
 });
```

and style is like this:

```
.gridTableSeparator 
{
  width: 3px; 
  right:-4px;
  height:40px;
  float:right;    
  position:relative;  
  cursor: e-resize;
  background-color: black;
}
.gridTableHeadline 
{
  line-height: 40px;  
  overflow: hidden;
}
#wrapper {
 overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Problem & Question:
the table width is limited by width's page when I resize columns, I have added a `div` with scrolling to let table's `width` exceeds `100%` but still fixed and not working see [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/drwhite/G4q8K/).

Is there any appropriate solution for this ?

PS: this is one of solution i found here [Resizable table columns with bz code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152837/resizable-table-columns-with-bz-code) and modified like demo in jsfiddle

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you want and what you have?

Comment: @NathanLee: what i have : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/drwhite/G4q8K/) and what i want : after resizing the table's width can attemps 300%